# How disable the 'k' dislay in Highcharts ordinate?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using  HighChart and when the data is load, the ordinate of the charts display a 'k' after the number for the thousands but I would like do not display the 'k'.

Example : `1 500k` -> `1 500`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change this for **all charts**, use [`lang.numericSymbols`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.numericSymbols): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t3hporya/

Snippet:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        numericSymbols: ['']
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [0.029, 71.5, 1.06, 1292, 14400, 1.760, 135, 1480, 0.0216, 0.194, 9.56, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own format using the format parameter

```
yAxis: { // can be xAxis too 
    labels: {
        format: function() {
            return value.substr(0, 1) + ' ' + value.substr(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method display the full number. Please see the example in my post.

Comment: do you want a space after the first integer?

Comment: you can use your own function to return a value that would print 1 500, highcharts is not for that purpose

Comment: I found the solution, in a function in formatter option I split the original string with `value.split("k");` and I return `value[0]`.

Note :  `value` is the original string.